# How to update record values through email body

Tags: apex, string, substring

I have a requirement to create case for specific subject email.I wrote an email service working well.

But now i try to capture some values from email body and need to updatein specific field.

Like

> Invoice Total Amount: 658.81 USD(includes taxes, shipping and handling)

I will try to use like emailBody[0].substring(22);

But, amount value will change accordingly.So i try to use string functions like ends with But i'm not able to achieve.

Comment: The subject will always be the same? Only the amount will change?

Comment: Yes only amount will change in the above template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure the subject will never change except for the amount, you should use the `substringBetween(open, close)` method of the [`String` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm). You can use the ':' character as open tag and 'USD' as close tag.

Then, you can use the `trim()` method of the `String` class to remove any leading or trailing white space characters.

Here's the code:

```
String amountStr = subject.substringBetween(':', 'USD').trim();
```

Comment: Works as expected mine is currency field converted to decimal.